# Cannot build an inner class which inherit NSObject

Tags: swift

Now, I can build the following code;

```
class Greeting {
  class Type {
    let str: String
    init(str: String) {
      self.str = str
    }
    func say(str: String) -> Void{}
  }
  class var HELLO: Type {
    class Hello: Type {
      override func say(str: String) {
      }
    }
    return Hello(str: "Hello")
  }
}
```

But, I cannot build the next;

```
class Greeting {
  class Type: NSObject {
    let str: String
    init(str: String) {
      self.str = str
    }
    func say(str: String) -> Void{}
  }
  class var HELLO: Type {
    class Hello: Type {
      override func say(str: String) {
      }
    }
    return Hello(str: "Hello")
  }
}
```

Xcode shows the error

```
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Compiling of nested types is very buggy currently. This is just a compiler bug.

Comment: Thanks! That’s what I thought.
Should I report this to bugreport.apple.com?

Comment: You can but it had been already reported multiple times.

Comment: OK. You've been very helpful! Thanks！